# Remounting my home directory?

Tags: mount

I'm in a bit of situation here:

I have linux mint 17, and on boot it says `Press S to skip mounting or M for manual Recovery`. So I press S

and when I try to login with my `username blue` it says

> Your home directory is listed as: '/home/blue'  but it does not appear to exist.

I logged in using `ctrl+alt+f1` and using `root`. I mounted `/dev/sda7` in `/mnt/sda7` to check if my files exist - they are. Inside `/mnt/sda7` there are 2 folders: `blue` and `lost+found`.

The `blue` folder is my home folder with all my stuff.

So: how exactly should I mount sda7 in order to fix the situation and how to make it persist rebooting? What is the exact mount command?

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to run a `fsck` manually while the drive is not mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was there a message before your "Press S to skip mounting or M for manual Recovery" message explaining why you're being prompted?  My guess is disk corruption.  Try unmounting /mnt/sda7 and then doing `fsck /dev/sda7` to check your disk for errors.  You can try to mount your filesystems using the `sudo mount -a` command

Comment: I added `/dev/sda7` to fstab and then `mount -a`.